# Do I need to apply for a visa to enter South Korea as a tourist on an Australian passport?

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, australian-citizens, south-korea

Do I need to apply for a visa to enter South Korea as a tourist for a few days when travelling on an Australian passport? Or will I be able to get one on arrival?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Australian Citizens **do not** require a visa when entering South Korea **as a tourist**.  [As of June 2014](http://aus-sydney.mofa.go.kr/english/as/aus-sydney/visa/issuance/index.jsp), Australian citizens no longer require a visa when entering **for business purposes**.

A good source for visa requirements is the [Star Alliance Website](http://www.staralliance.com/en/services/visa-and-health/). For South Korea you will need to select "Korea (Rep. of)"

Comment: Even no visa for business purposes? Wow, I only knew that it was so easy for tourism!

Comment: Read it again - Australians DO need a visa for business.  On my first trip there in 1999 no visa was required for business, however when I returned 1-2 years later they had just introduced that they were required.

Answer (score 4):

No us Aussies don't need anything special for South Korea if we're just tourists.

I'm Australian and in the past 2 years or so I've popped in and out of Korea about seven times I think and the process is perfectly painless.

I believe we get ninety days and another Aussie sitting next to me who's just been there also recalls it as ninety days.